# Styling borders for table cell

Tags: html, css

If we want to achieve the following, i.e. style the border in such a way that the border will have the thick right bottom corner and upon hover show a plus sign.

[image]

**What I have done**: I have done selection of cells in tables. Normal borders. Even tried border styling, but most of which is rounded or cut-off borders, which is not of use here.

**What I am trying to do**: I am trying to mimic series fill functionality of excel in html table. Functionality is not a problem. I am just trying to get the styling of these borders right so that it is easier to comprehend.

So, How can we customize the border to get the desired effect only using css and html?
select.js

```
     $(function () {
        $('td').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        });
     });
```

table.html

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="15">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>57</td>
            <td>62</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

table.css

```
     .highlight {
         border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
         border: 2px solid black; 
     }
```

Comment: You'd probably have to use an image to style the border.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you have to far, to see how you are defining the selection itself. I would imagine you'd have to absolutely position psuedo elements, but it's hard to say at this stage.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect what I have done until now.

Comment: What's the point of border-radius and what exactly isn't working? Also, you can show your little icon by either manipulating the cursor, or just insert the graphic into the DOM as needed and then set the position absolutely to the bottom right corner of your active cell.

Comment: I added the point of border radius just to emphasize that I am not looking at that part (rounded edges or cut off edges) for which i got most of the search results for.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

I went back and added a different behavior to each cell after looking at ther image I believe I understand now See updated Snippet.

---

It has been brought to my attention that you probably don't want every cell that way (I tend to go into automatic coding, like a robot .) I modified it so that the last cell will have the `div.pad`.

---

Did you mean a square on every cell or just the table? If the latter, let me know, it's an easy adjustment. I used

- `position: relative` and `absolute`
- `z-index`
- `border-collapse: separate`
- `border-spacing`, `border`, and `outline`
- Pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`
- 2 unicode entities `\1f4c4`  and `\2795`  ➕
- and the pseudo-class `:hover` of course.
- Added `tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type` to single out the last cell.

It looks bulky  because there's no dimensions mentioned, but that's fine since the bulkiness highlights the styles and how they interact. Each square is a div that is a child of a cell (`<td>`). Making the cells `relative` whilst the divs are `absolute` allows us to give it coordinates in relation to the `<td>` edges. Once positioned in the bottom right corner, we give the div some dynamic content that appears on `:hover`. When `:hover`ed upon, the pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` appear. They to are `position`ed, but with a `relative` value because we want to move the fonts of `::before` and `::after` relative to their original position, rather than to another `position`ed element (like we did previously with each`<td>` and div.

Special note on the `div.pad`'s styling.

- `position:absolute` allowed us to easily pick the bottom right corner. If `bottom:0` and `right:0` puts `.pad` snugly into the corner, then we can continue going forward with negative length values in order for `.pad` to sit halfway in and halfway out of cell/table borders.
- Added `outline:2px solid white` instead of `border` because unlike border, `outline` width doesn't displace other elements in the layout. The white color is to blend into the background giving the appearance of `.pad` being more of a separate yet related component of the table.
- `z-index:1` was also given to `.pad` so that the white outline is clearly defined from the table borders.

The other main points are:

- The borders were made so that they were defined as separate properties but appeared as one border (like `border-collapse: collapse;`) To avoid that disconnected look the `border-collapse:separate` gives, we use `outline` to fill in that `border-spacing of 1px;` if we were to use only borders, the table as a whole would increase noticeably in size. The border and outline styles are `inset` and the last cell has an over sized outline style `outset` designating it as highlighted.

**SNIPPET**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border: 1px inset black;
  outline: 1px inset black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 150px;
}

td {
border:1px solid black;
outline: 1px inset black;
}

td:hover {
  border: -3px inset black;
  outline: 6px outset black;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  padding:1px;
}

.pad {
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
}

td:hover .pad, 
.pad:hover {
  border: 4px solid black;
  bottom: -9px;
  right: -9px;
  outline: 2px solid white;
  z-index:2;
  padding:2px;
}

.pad:hover::before {
  content: '\1f4c4';
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  z-index:2;
}

.pad:hover::after {
  content: '\2795';
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 24px;
  font-size: .7rem;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='pad'></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I do think OP only wants just one corner.

Comment: Not sure if that's what he wants, but nice nonetheless.